# Trying to Integrate Custom Javascript to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, integration

http://burchsheetmetal.com/wordpress/color-selector/

Hello!

I am having trouble with the html integration code on my wordpress page.

My integration code is this:

```
<div  class="colorselector" data-colorselector='{"path":"wordpress","wp-
content","themes","thegem-
child","colorselector","assets":"onChange":"onColorSelectorChange"}'>
</div>
```

despite multiple attempts, the file is still not linking...
Could anyone help a noob out?
I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: That is html with json info. Not JS.

Comment: The path in data-colorselector looks wrong. It should probably be "path":"wordpress/wp-
content/themes/thegem-child/colorselector/assets"

Answer (score 0):

Try this with edited path:

```
<div class="colorselector" data-colorselector='{"path":"wordpress/wp-
content/themes/thegem-child/colorselector/assets", "onChange":"onColorSelectorChange"}'>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider marking the answer as accepted to remove this question from the "unanswered questions" list.